# Splitting and using source code (Updated) Form won't pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok I've literally been trying to get the source code for the fancybox inline popup but I can't seem to get it. I put the code together perfectly but my webpage crashes when I try to save it to my `site builder`.

Fancybox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples (I'm trying to get "Inline - auto detect width / height" near the bottom of the webpage)

Here's what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js">   </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  /* change the media content paddings and margins
  if the screen's max-width is just 900px
  if total width is 900px only..*/
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li>
   <a id="various1" href="#inline1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Inline - auto detect width / height
   </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @tymeJV I don't know of any recent ones and Fancybox supports multiple browsers.

Comment: I was trying to find what version of jQuery that Fancybox requires, but couldn't find anything definite. According to the [Fancybox changelog](http://fancybox.net/changelog/), there was a recent bug fix in Fancybox 1.3.3: "Ajax is now working with jQuery 1.3+". While it still may be the case that such an old version of jQuery is causing an issue, it may not be since the changelog implies support of an even older version of jQuery. @user2680614 A more recent version of jQuery that still supports older browsers (e.g. IE6+) would be any jQuery 1.x.x (1.10.x is latest). jQuery 2.x supports IE9+.

Comment: @ajp15243 ok I found this http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples but I don't know how to copy the source correctly so I can put it on my website. I don't know what I'm doing wrong though.

Comment: Well, you just need to copy/paste the HTML into your page, inside the `<body> </body>` tags. Then copy/paste the JS into a `<script> </script>` tag. Make sure you also have `<script>` tags for jQuery and Fancybox (I would change the jQuery link to be something newer than 1.4), and the `<link>` tag for the Fancybox CSS.  Then you should be able to just load that markup file with a browser and it should work.

Comment: Ok did that but the code still doesn't function properly. It doesn't freeze anymore but it also doesn't popup like it should. I can post what I have if you want to see it @ajp15243

Answer (score 1):

What they're using, can be done by

1. CSS using media query
2. jQuery, but using the latest version. You're using an old one! Get the latest one here: http://www.jquery.com in their footer!

**Using CSS:**

You can do using CSS, is this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 /* change the media content paddings and margins
 if the screen's max-width is just 900px
 if total width is 900px only..*/
}
```

You can then change the `max-width: 900px` to any other screen size, when you want to change the footer and other element's padding or width or other css properties.

**If you want to use jQuery:**

Then you can use:

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
  $('footer').css('padding', '20px');
}
```

This code will change the padding of footer tag to 20px, if window.width is less than 960!

This is what they are using. Secondly, the live shifting of the `footer` is because of percentage padding **maybe**. Because it gets shifted automatically; then the guess would be of the percentage padding.

Comment: That's helpful but I need to know what I did wrong inside of the code above that I posted before I can even add or make changes.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see any of your code there! All I see is the stuff that should be in `head` tag. Nothing else. Can you show me any jQuery or CSS? I will tell you where you were wrong. You can just try to update the jquery version. :) That will fix it I guess,

Comment: Ok I updated the code above. I did everything right just like you said but why won't the lightbox popup?

Comment: Ok, now I get the point! What you're doing is totally wrong. i was using a comment just to provide an example. You should remove the `/**/` block and replace it with `footer {padding: 10px;}`. This will change the code. Secondly Please have a tutorial about css media query! Because you have just written the code as provided. Nothing else! :(

Comment: I see but I checked it out and fixed it but can you look at my code above and maybe tell me why it's not popping up when I click on it? It may have something to do with the javascript or css but I added the external sheets so there shouldn't be.

Comment: When you want to do something using click, then you must have this code `$('selecter').click(function() {//code});` do you have this?